# Use foldLeft to replace occurrences of character in String

Tags: scala

I'm trying to learn functional Scala and working on a simple problem - replace occurrences of `\'` or  `\\` contained in a String:

Here is my code so far:

```
val data : String = "\' this is a test \\ "

    data.toCharArray.foldLeft(""){ (x, y) => x match {
      case Nil => y :: Nil
      case head :: tail =>
        if head == '\'' ''
        else if head == '\\' ''
        else head :: tail
    }
```

There are multiple errors:

[image]

[image]

I've not understood something fundamental with fold?

Simple examples of foldLeft such as:

```
val sum = prices.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _)
```

are understandable but I'm unsure how to use foldLeft in a context where there is conditions. In the problem I posted the condition being matching on a character.

Comment: You haven't closed closure's brackets. You only closed `match`. And you cannot use matchers for `List` on `Array`

Comment: Correction: actually you used `List` matchers on `Char`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in this code:

- you haven't closed lambda's bracket
- you use `List` pattern matching on... well string because
- `x` here is result so far (so `""` initially) and `y` are elements of data (chars)

This code should look like this:

```
val data : String = "\' this is a test \\ "

data.toCharArray.foldLeft("") { (result, ch) =>
  if (ch == '\'' || ch == '\\') result
  else result + ch
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here, starting with some syntactic problems, like missing parentheses around the conditionals. The first real substantive issue is that the initial value (the `""` in `foldLeft("")`) must be the same type as the accumulator, and as the return type. You seem to want a `List[Char]` as the return type, so you'll need to use something like `List.empty[Char]` as the initial value.

Next I'd strongly recommend using names like `acc` and `c` instead of `x` and `y` to indicate more clearly which is the accumulator and which is the current value.

Another issue is that `''` also isn't valid Scala syntax—there is no empty character literal. I'll use `'_'` as the replacement just for the sake of example.

A working implementation might look like this:

```
val data: String = "\' this is a test \\ "

data.toCharArray.foldLeft(List.empty[Char]) { (acc, c) =>
  c match {
    case '\'' => acc :+ '_'
    case '\\' => acc :+ '_'
    case other => acc :+ other
  }
}
```

Which yields:

```
val data: String = "' this is a test \ "
val res1: List[Char] = List(_,  , t, h, i, s,  , i, s,  , a,  , t, e, s, t,  , _,  )
```

Which I think is what you're aiming for?

As a footnote, I'm assuming this is just an exercise, but it's worth noting that using a left fold for an operation like this is extremely inefficient, since you're building up a list by appending.

Comment: thanks, yes it's must a learning exercise, instead of using leftFold what would you suggest ?

Comment: If you actually just want to replace characters in a string, then the `java.lang.String` API is almost certainly the best approach (i.e. the `replace` methods). If you're doing something a little more complicated, or the characters are in a list already, then maybe `map` or `flatMap`. In some cases you might need a fold for complex logic, but if you're building up a list in a fold, you want a right fold (which lets you prepend instead of appending).

Comment: "Which I think is what you're aiming for?" partly as I aiming to remove the characters. I accept I should have clarified that. But your answer nevertheless has aided my understanding , thanks!